# something wrong with environment variables, won't build: using Netbeans writing C/C++

Tags: netbeans, environment-variables

there's definitely something wrong with setting up my environment variables.

I had messed around with it when I was trying to do an android app. 
now i'm trying to set up netbeans, but it won't build.

when I first tried to build, tool selection came out, and it had looked for `cygwin` bin files in `D:` instead of `C:`, so I manually browsed for each file.

i found g++ make etc. however, I couldn't find `gfortran.exe`. 
now, a message says that it can't find shell, and asks me to install `cygwin`.

this is what i have in my path:

```
D:\DAC driver and stuff\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
D:\matlab\MATLAB\runtime\win64;
D:\matlab\MATLAB\bin;C:\cygwin64\bin
```

and yes, cygwin is in C:\cygwin64

this is a picture of everything i have in my environment variables:

http://i567.photobucket.com/albums/ss114/samio_130/cake/pictwoo.png

edit: i think i deleted something from 'path'! should there be something infront of what i currently have??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%JAVA_HOME%\bin is no legit. Everything after it doesn't count, fix is in link.

http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=151733#151733